# SAX Parser - Extract string within tags

Tags: java, xml, parsing, saxparser

This is my problem: i need to extract the text between the tag "`p`" without the XML notation using SAX Parser

```
    <title>1. Introduction</title>
    <p>The Lorem ipsum 
           <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="B1">
                1
           </xref>. 
           Lorem ipsum 23.
     </p>
     <p>The L domain recruits an ATP-requiring cellular factor for this 
           scission event, the only known energy-dependent step in assembly 
           <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="B2">
                2
           </xref>. 
           Domain is used here to denote the amino 
           acid sequence that constitutes the biological function.
     </p>
```

Is it possible using `endElement()` ? Because when i use it i obtain only the part after "`/xref`" tag

Here the code

```
public void endElement(String s, String s1, String element) throws SAXException {

        if(element.equals(Finals.PARAGRAPH)){
            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
            paragraph.setContext(tmpValue);
            System.out.println("Contesto: " + tmpValue);
            listP.add(paragraph);

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ac, int i, int j) throws SAXException {
        tmpValue = new String(ac, i, j);

    }
```

This is what i expect to do: a list `listP` containing the two paragraphs:

```
1) Lorem ipsum 1 Lorem ipsum 23.
2) The L domain recruits an ATP-requiring cellular factor for this 
       scission event, the only known energy-dependent step in assembly 2 
       Domain is used here to denote the amino 
       acid sequence that constitutes the biological function.
```

Comment: Because obviously `endElement` is invoked on ... ending elements. You are interested in a section called CDATA. You should find the appropriate handler for this. And you should present your current attempt using your actual code.

Comment: Seems you're doing fine. Where's the problem?

Comment: I need this result `The L domain recruits an ATP-requiring cellular factor for this  scission event, the only known energy-dependent step in assembly 2. Domain is used here to denote the amino acid sequence that constitutes the biological function.`
but i get only `Domain is used here to denote the amino acid sequence that constitutes the biological function.`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "is it possible using endElement", but it's certainly possible. You'd need to write your SAX application so it:

(1) ignores all `startElement`/`endElement` events between the ones for the `<p>`aragraph -- simple state tracking, or perhaps you can simply say that you aren't interested in elements other than paragraphs and make your element event handlers be no-ops for anything you don't care about.

(2) accumulates separately-delivered `characters()` events until the `endElement` for the `<p>`aragraph. But you need to do this anyway, because SAX *always* reserves the right to deliver contiguous text as several `characters()` calls, for reasons having to do with parser buffer management.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible solutions. Usually using SAX parsers you just add some boolean flags to denote some particular states when parsing. In this simple example you can achieve this with just changing this:

```
tmpValue = new String(ac, i, j);
```

to this:

```
if (tmpValue.equals(""))
    tmpValue = new String(ac, i, j);
else
    tmpValue += new String(ac, i, j);
```

or:

```
if (tmpValue == null)
    tmpValue = new String(ac, i, j);
else
    tmpValue += new String(ac, i, j);
```

Depending on how you initialize the `tmpValue` variable (and you should initialize it if you're not doing it already).

To gather contents of all paragraphs you need to:

```
public void endElement(String s, String s1, String element) throws SAXException {

    if (element.equals(Finals.PARAGRAPH)) {
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
        paragraph.setContext(tmpValue);
        System.out.println("Contesto: " + tmpValue);
        listP.add(paragraph);
        tmpValue = ""; // or tmpValue = null; for the second version
    }
}
```

and to omit the title part:

```
public void startElement(
    String uri,
    String localName,
    String qName,
    Attributes atts) {

    if (localName.equals(Finals.PARAGRAPH)) {
        tmpValue = ""; // or tmpValue = null; for the second version
    }
}
```

Comment: I get nullPointerException adding that solution.

Comment: @user3162945 Please be specific. I've provided two solutions. Also do have `tmpValue` initialized, as I have suggested?

Comment: I forgot to initialize `tmpValue`. Now works but i didn't get the full string. Only the part after `/xref`

Comment: @user3162945 I misunderstood your initial requirement. Check this edit.

Comment: It works but  it takes everything in the xml. I need only the part in `p` tag. Check my edit.

Comment: @user3162945 Only the part in which `p` tag? I ask you again, to be as specific as possible. Regardless of that just add some boolean flags and set them appropriately in `startElement` and `endElements`, it's as easy as that...

Comment: I need to collect paragraphs so i need a list of what is betweeen the tag `p`. In the exemple what i expect is a list `listP` of two elements

Comment: @user3162945 ... this is all trivial, but all right - yet another edit.

Comment: In this case i get the title too, but i don't need it. I need only paragraphs. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @user3162945 All right - see the edit. That's my final fix. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `stack`
`Push` in `startElement` events and `Pop` in `endElement` events.

Or if that doesn't work for you, just `Push` into the stack for all events and then after `endOfDocument`, `Pop` the elements one by one. Store the data from `</p>` to `<p>` in reverse.